# View messing up clicks when changed from GONE to VISIBLE

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following (Relative) layout (from top to bottom):

- Top bar with an icon which opens an options menu
- Hidden menu which is set to `Visibility.GONE` until it is opened
- RecyclerView beneath, it takes up the remainder of the screen

So in the beginning, only the top bar and the `RecyclerView` are visible.
When I click to display the hidden menu, it opens up and lowers the `RecyclerView` down to make space for itself. If I click on the buttons inside of this hidden menu, they work. The tricky part is, if I click on empty space between those buttons (*screen area where the RecyclerView elements USED to be*), the click is passed on to a certain RecyclerView element. 
So instead of nothing happening because I clicked on empty space, my clicks get passed on to the `RecyclerView` which used to be there before the options menu popped up.

I am not using animations, only `view.visibility = View.VISIBLE`

Edit: Let me know if you guys need some photos for better understanding.

Here is my XML:

```
<!-- TOP BAR -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/topBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="47dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/topBarButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- RecyclerView -->
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/hiddenMenu"/>

<!-- Hidden menu -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/hiddenMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/topBar"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/hiddenMenutext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="This is some text" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/hiddenMenuImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show xml with code

Comment: please share your XML code

Answer (score 0):

Can u try this..... if not solved share the exact issue with images/Gif.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lltop"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout

            android:id="@+id/topBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="47dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/topBarButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/hiddenMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/hiddenMenutext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="This is some text" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/hiddenMenuImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lltop"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/item_margin"
android:clipToPadding="false"/>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Cool suggestion, unfortunately getting the same result. Apparently when the HiddenMenu appears, the screen still keeps the old coordinates of the RecyclerView. I need a way to tell it that something has changed.

Comment: Share what you do ?